# Lubuntu can't get into promiscuous mode

Tags: linux, networking, wifi

I'm using wireshark on lubuntu to sniff on my wifi(WPA-PSK encrypted).
No frames from other ip's are shown.
Tried 
ifconfig wlan0 promisc
But without result.

Anyone Suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure there is actually traffic from other IP's?

Answer (score 4):

Not all wifi adapters allow promiscuous mode, you may have one. And what's more, libpcap can't do it natively. WireShark's wiki has [some tips](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN) on getting it running. Specifically, you'll probably need the aircrack-ng packages and use the airmon-ng script included in it.